# JQuery $('#id').val('{{ $item->var}}') does not display accents correctly

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Hello fellow developers,

I am having an issue with jQuery and accents (á, é, í, ó, ú). 
I am using Laravel and PostgreSQL and all accented characters are being displayed correctly in the database and when I display the value like this:

```
<p> {{ $item->var }} </p>
```

But when I do the following:

```
<input id="id" type="text" class="class"/>
$('#id').val('{{ $var->item }}');
```

The accent in the word shows up HTML encoded:

> &aacute

My head tag already has the following charset:

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

I also tried

```
$('#id').html('{{ $var->item}}').text
```

but since it's an input tag, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this but it should work. You need to output it in raw mode. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

```
$('#id').val("{!! $var->item !!}");
```

Comment: It is exactly that! Thank you for your prompt answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!